# Change Calendar Month View to show fewer weeks

Tags: macos, calendar

Using iCal Version 10.0 (2195.4.3) on an iMac running OS 10.13.6. The calendar app used to allow the **month view** to show fewer than 6 weeks. That preference doesn't seem to be available now. Can the number of weeks be changed?

Comment: Please don't cross-post to multiple SE sites. Pick one & stick to it, or flag for migration.
[Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/) - https://superuser.com/questions/1828087/change-calendar-month-view-to-show-fewer-weeks and the very similar https://superuser.com/questions/1827845/how-to-display-3-weeks-instead-of-6-weeks-in-monthly-view-in-the-macos-calendar from the day before.

Answer (score 0):

I've checked back in old VMs of OS X. It was never adjustable, but did change the number of weeks displayed.

Up to Lion [10.7], the app was called iCal & showed 5 weeks, not adjustable. In 2012, Mountain Lion [10.8] it became Calendar & then showed 6 weeks, again not adjustable.

Comment: A month can spawn up to 6 weeks if the first day is on a weekend, so it kind of makes sense to show 6 weeks at once in **month** view.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question

Comment: Sure it is. The number of weeks cannot be changed. There never was a pref.

Comment: I love it when askers downvote me because the answer is "It can't be done, & never could."